# jQuery equivalent of || or ?? operator

Tags: jquery

Using plain JavaScript I can do stuff like this:

```
var ninjaTurtle = document.getElementById('raphael') ||
                  document.getElementById('leonardo');
```

If the first DOM lookup returns `null`, which is falsy, the second lookup is evaluated.

The jQuery function `$()` always returns i jQuery array-like object, even when no elements are matched. Even when empty, this object is not falsy, hence the following expression will never evaluate the right hand side:

```
var ninjaTurtle = $('#raphael') || $('#leonardo');
```

So, what is the idiomatic way of doing this kind of fallback when using jQuery?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Checking the matched/returned element count will tell you if your selector matched something or not... 
[fallback](http://forrst.com/posts/jQuery_fallback_function-Y8m) is a simple utility plugin which lets you do that gracefully...

```
jQuery.fn.fallback = function(elem) {
    return 0 < this.length ? this : $(elem);
};
```

The best part of this function is you can chain as many as needed until you find a matched element..

`$('#raphael').fallback('#leonardo').fallback('#kilik').dosomething();`

Comment: I just put together the same thing, although I called it `or`. Perhaps `fallback` is more descriptive.

Comment: Great minds think alike… I wrote the very same function 20 minutes ago, but thought "stop - this ought to be built into jQuery". Judging from the answers here, it's not.

Comment: Btw, I named my function `or` after considering also `else` and `fallback`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var ninjaTurtle = $('#raphael').length ?  $('#raphael') : $('#leonardo');
```

Comment: It seems a bit wasteful to look up `#raphael` twice, though.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the way of doing it. The shortest things that comes to my mind is:

```
var ninjaTurtle = $('#raphael').length ? $('#raphael') : $('#leonardo');
```

Comment: That will however do the search for the first selector twice if it finds anything.