# Find fallback element in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

JavaScript has very nice syntax for fallbacks and defaults, as long as unsuccessful calls return a falsy value:

```
var element = findElement() || findSomeOtherElement() || makeALastAttempt();
```

jQuery selectors are, however, truthy even when they are empty.
Is there an elegant way if saying "I want the element at this selector, and if it does not exist, then the element at that selector"?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery equivalent of || or ?? operator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7190126/jquery-equivalent-of-or-operator)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not using:

```
jQuery.fn.exists = function(){
if(this.length>0) 
    return this;
return false; };


var a = ($(selector1).exists() || $(selector2).exists());
```

Comment: isn't `this` already a jQuery object ? `jQuery.fn.exists = function(){ return this.length > 0 ? this : false; };`

Comment: This should work, but having an `exists()` function behave like a getter seems like a code smell

Comment: I would go with `$.fn.orElse = function(s) {return this.length ? this : $(s)}`. But I was hoping there is a nice way to do this without extending jQuery.

Answer (score 6):

If you expect only one element you can do this:

```
var element = $(findElement()[0] || findSomeOtherElement()[0] || makeALastAttempt()[0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Will select an element with name `anchorName`and if not found select another element with ID `#anchorName`

```
$("[name=anchorName], #anchorName").first()
```

Comment: Worth pointing out: this will select `#anchorName` when both exist and `#anchorName` is encountered in the DOM first

Answer (score 1):

If you're only wanting a single element as your result, I ended up with:

```
$('#preferred-element').add($('#fallback-element')).first();
```

Answer (score 0):

No. Sorry, you'll have to use the `.length` property. This is a side effect of Javascript evaluating all objects as truthy, and obviously a jQuery selector is functionally an object. However, the resulting syntax is not so bad:

```
$(function(){
  var element = $('.findElement'),
      otherElement = $('.findSomeOtherElement'),
      lastAttempt = $('.lastAttempt');

  var elegance = (element.length && element)
      || (otherElement.length && otherElement)
      || (lastAttempt.length && lastAttempt);

  elegance.css('border','1px solid green');
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/aNuNz/1/)**

Comment: This is nice but loses the short-circuit of the original code ;) (i.e. all three every selectors are executed even if the first matches something)

Comment: @arnaud: True, but if you want that you can always inline the whole thing. I just precalculated the selectors for readability.

Comment: That is a clever solution, but hard to read, even with precalculation.

Answer (score 0):

Heres an answer a lot closer to what was actually desired.

```
var fallback = function(options){
    var numOfOptions = options.length;
    if (numOfOptions == 2){
        return (options[0].length > 0)? options[0] : options[1];
    }else if (numOfOptions > 2){
        return fallback(options.slice(1));
    }else if (numOfOptions == 1){
        return options[0];
    }else{
        return $();
    }
};
fallback([$(selector1),$(selector2),$(selector3)]);
```